# Update statement with corelated subquery: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: sql, oracle19c

Environment: Oracle 19

These are the my two tables -

```
MainTab ( g_year, g_prd, match_col, desc)
```

MainTab is range partitioned on g_year and sub-paritioned on g_prd

```
LookupTab ( match_col, desc)
```

I want to update MainTab's desc column using LookupTab. I am executing below update query on just one sub-partition.

```
update MainTab a  
SET a.desc = (SELECT distinct b.desc FROM LookupTab b 
                    where a.g_year =2005 and a.g_prd = 1 and a.desc is null 
                            and a.match_col = b.match_col and b.desc is not null )
where a.g_year =2005 and  a.g_prd = 1 and a.desc is null;
```

This query is throwing `ORA-01427 - single-row subquery returns more than one row` even though I have distinct clause in subquery.

Question : Why the `distinct` clause and additional where clause `b.desc is not null` are not able to prevent multiple rows from being returned in the sub query.

I could fix this by using `fetch first 1  row only`  but I expected `distinct` clause to work as well.

Comment: then your b.desc is not distinct.

Comment: I think that could be possible. I will do some testing to verify . Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misunderstood `DISTINCT`. That doesn't limit a result to one row, it just makes sure that every row (the complete one) is `DISTINCT` within the result and usually there can be many distinct rows.

And as a side note: `a.g_year =2005 and a.g_prd = 1 and a.desc is null` in the `WHERE` of the subquery is pointless, it's true whatsoever because it's also the operation in the outer `WHERE`.

Answer (score 1):

As Sticky Bit says, "Distinct" will return each unique value in that column. Try running this part separately and see if you get more than 1 row returned. I suspect you will:

```
SELECT distinct b.desc FROM LookupTab b 
                    where a.g_year =2005 and a.g_prd = 1 and a.desc is null 
                            and a.match_col = b.match_col and b.desc is not null
```

As commented above as well, you don't need the `WHERE` clause twice. One place or the other is fine.

You will likely need to be more specific with your inner `WHERE` and remove the `distinct` part.